# CIUnit Testing foostack

Tags: codeigniter, phpunit

Is there anyone here used [CIUnit](http://foostack.com/)?

Having trouble understanding it. T_T.

What I'm doing is pretty simple

E.g

I have a controller method myphp()

```
function myphp()
{
 echo 'boom';
}
```

CI Unit Testing:

```
public function setUp()
{
    // Set the tested controller
    $this->CI = set_controller('home');
           // date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
}


function testMyPhp()
{
    $this->CI->myphp();

    $out = output();
    var_dump($out); //return empty eventhough function myphp is returning a string ('boom')
}
```

What happening.?? I just want to test whether I can fetch the output of my method myphp.

Comment: What is output()? What version of CI are you using? That fooStack site says the latest version they've tested on was 1.7.2 which is very old now.

Comment: empty ".string(0) ". I'm using CI 2.1.0.

Comment: No I mean what is output the function, like literally what does it do? I don't recall a native PHP or CI helper function of that name. Is it your own helper? CI 2.1.0 is very different to 1.7.2, you might have to simply accept that this CIUnit doesn't support 2.1.0

Comment: fetched the buffered output. In my case it fetch the return of myphp function. So supposedly it should output a string 'boom'

Comment: Try [this fork](https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit/overview) of the CIUnit, I'm using the `0.18-dev_for_CI2.1.0` branch with codeigniter version 2.1.2 successfuly.